# Remove all values from an array that are not even

Tags: javascript, arrays

New to JS, and I came across this problem. I know I'm just missing something. I appreciate any help with an answer. I included my attempted code. (Dont laugh.)

```
//Loop through arr removing all values that aren't even 
//hint x % 2 --> checks for even numbers

var arr = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
for (var i = 0; i > arr.length; i++) {
    while (i % 2 !== 0) {
        arr.splice(i);
    }
}
alert(arr);
```

Comment: Um, splice takes at least two parameters.

Comment: Is there a problem with the code you have? What's your question?

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the splice error. (That should have been an obvious mistake.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
 var arr = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
 for ( var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i-- ) {
      if( arr[i] % 2 !== 0 ) {
      // splice takes two arguments at least index to start removing and the number of elements to remove
         arr.splice( i, 1 );
     }
 }

 console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Thanks! I chose this answer because it was the best for my current level of JS knowledge.

Answer (score 4):

This is a nice trick I got from a gist, you actually need to use a reverse loop to avoid messing the index

```
for (var i = arr.length; i >= 0; i--) {
     if (i % 2 !== 0) {
        arr.splice(i);
     }
}
```

This is a crossbrowser option, you can also use the filter as @agreco says but is not available in every browser

Answer (score 3):

You could also use [.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) if you're targeting newer browsers or node:

```
var arr2 = arr.filter(function(o) {
  return o % 2 !== 0;
});
```

Comment: Cool. I haven't seen **filter** yet, so thanks for the introduction.

Answer (score 1):

```
var arr = [1,2,3,6,22,98,45,23,22,12];
var arr2=[];
arr.forEach(function(e){if (e%2!==0) arr2.push(e)});
alert(arr2);
```

So you have the array called `arr`, and you want to build a new array from this one. You attach a method that is built into modern javascript called "forEach" which means that for each value of the array, it executes the function between the `()`. The variable `e` means element, and it gives you access to the current array item that it is on. So if e%2!==0 (aka if e is odd), push it to the new array. Then after its looped through everything, you have your new array.